# Find the enclosing f of return in anonymous funcion

Tags: scala

In Scala Language Specification 6.20 Return Expressions, it says:
"A return expression return e must occur inside the body of some enclosing named method or function.The innermost enclosing named method or function in a source program, f..."

There is a `innermost enclosing f` here, and I want to find that `f` for `return`. But when it comes to anonymous function, things becomes a little complicated.

Example1: The innermost enclosing f here is `f1`. In the decompiled java code, we can see that the exception is caught by `f1`.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) { 
  def f1() { () => return }
}
```

Example2: The innermost enclosing f here is still `f1`. In the decompiled java code, we can see that the exception is still caught by `f1`, even though, from the execution view, `f2` is `return`'s innermost enclosing f.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) { 
  def f2(x: Any) { println(x) }
  def f1() { f2(() => return) }
}
```

Perhaps we can say, that in Example2, `x` is not trully executed in f2. But here is another weird example.

Example3: The innermost enclosing f here is `main`, not map and println.(But I know that the class file of map or println cannot be changed here.)

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val list = List(1, 2, 3)
  println(list.map(x => return x * 2))
}
```

In a word, it seems that this `innermost enclosing f` is exactly the method with that exact def which contains the return expression directly.

Am I right?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you think `f2` encloses the `return`? The `return` is enclosed by `f1`, `f1` is enclosed by `main`, `f2` doesn't even enter the picture. In your last example, there is only one function, `main`, so obviously it must be the enclosing function, since there is no other function.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Emmmmmm...In the last example, there are other methods like println and map.The "enclosing definition" from Andrey just makes me clear. I entangled myself in the invocation order too much. Anyway, thanks for the comment on my strange question.

Comment: The `return` isn't inside the body of `map`. The body of `map` isn't even shown there. The only body that is there, is `main`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. "Enclosing" refers to "enclosing **def**inition".

As you yourself have noticed, it cannot refer to "enclosing method invocations", because then even something as simple as the following canonical use case of an early `return`:

```
def findFirstGreaterZero(as: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
  for (a <- as) {
    if (a > 0) return Some(a)
  }
  None
}
```

wouldn't work, even though there are no explicit lambdas in here. The `for` would desugar to `(a <- as).foreach{ a => ... return }`, and if the `{ a => ... return ...}` would "enclose" the `return` keyword, the `return` would only return from the current invocation of the body of `foreach`, instead of returning from the method `findFirstGreaterZero`, which would make `return` mostly useless.

Comment: "it cannot refer to "enclosing method invocations"" – That is already obvious from the fact that the spec talks about "bodies" and "source text", both of which are static syntactic elements, not dynamic ones.

Comment: The "enclosing definition" is really suitable here. And I'm enlightened by the example. I was focused on the anonymous function too much to noticed the common situation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Oh, you give me a more detailed way to understand the spec. I'm not an English native speaker, those details sometimes just slipped out of my eyes.